# Verification of maven property value

Tags: validation, maven, properties

There is a pom with a property:

```
<properties>
    <prop.name>some.value</prop.name>
</properties>
```

"some.value" is generated and might contain illegal characters, in which case a build should fail.

What is the best way of validation of property value at build time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a rule in the enforcer to specifically check for a property, the rule can also check the value of the property: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html